# What does those D3DCOMPILE constants mean?

Tags: hlsl, direct3d

In the D3DCompiler library there's these flags called ["D3DCompile Constants"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/d3dcompile-constants), but the description that Microsoft give us about them is very brief and difficult to have proper understanding of what they do. I wish someone could be able to explain at least what those three mean:

```
D3DCOMPILE_PARTIAL_PRECISION, D3DCOMPILE_NO_PRESHADER, D3DCOMPILE_ALL_RESOURCES_BOUND
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doc page is pretty poor. It's just the content of `D3DCompiler.h` comments put into a Markdown page. I'll see about submitting some edits to help it at least a little. Most of these flags are aliases for older D3DX constants as listed on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/d3dxshader-flags) where they are better documented at the moment.

**UPDATE**: The [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/d3dcompile-constants) page has been updated.

The `D3DCOMPILE_PARTIAL_PRECISION` flag is equivalent to FXC's `/Gpp` switch and is an alias for `D3DXSHADER_PARTIALPRECISION`. It basically treats `float32` values as `float16` in some cases and enable use of some approximation functions.

The `D3DCOMPILE_NO_PRESHADER` flag is equivalent to FXC's `/Op` switch and is an alias for `D3DXSHADER_PARTIALPRECISION`. This feature is deprecated and only applies to legacy Direct3D 9 era "Effects" (FX). See [this Microsoft Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/using-an-effect#improve-performance-with-preshaders) for what this was about.

`D3DCOMPILE_RESOURCES_MAY_ALIAS`, `D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_UNBOUNDED_DESCRIPTOR_TABLES`, and `D3DCOMPILE_ALL_RESOURCES_BOUND` flags are HLSL options for informing the HLSL compiler some assumptions when performing optimizations for DirectX 12 Shader Model 5.1.

Note for DirectX 12, D3DCompile and FXC.EXE are legacy and only support Shader Model 5.1. For DirectX12, you should use Shader Model 6 via the DXIL compiler and DXC.EXE command-line tool. See [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler/tree/master/docs).

Comment: Thank you very much, it's much more clear for me now. I'm considering to use `D3DCOMPILE_PARTIAL_PRECISION` flag.

Comment: So I basically rewrote that page in [this PR](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/pull/1141).